# TaskList for VisualStudio like in Mylyn

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I'm looking for plugin to VS that works just like 
[eclipse's mylyn's task list](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-mylyn1/)

EDIT:

I'm looking for standalone version, I'm a single developer and I don't need any bugzilla.

Comment: can you describe would should it do in two words?

Comment: @Stecya, read here description of plugin: [Mylyn Homepage](http://eclipse.org/mylyn/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364061.aspx) has same features. For example, short description of task tracking:

> Work items is another major object
>   that teams use to prioritize and track
>   and work. Work comes in many forms:
>   bugs, tasks, features, requirements,
>   change requests, issues, and so forth.
>   Most teams today need to deal with
>   several different tools to make sure
>   they are getting a clear picture of
>   everything that needs to be done. Team
>   Foundation Server has the flexibility
>   to manage all of these types of
>   objects as different work item types,
>   but tracks them in one place, allowing
>   for cross work item type reporting and
>   queries. All work items include things
>   such as a description, assigned user,
>   and states for tracking progress.
>   However, with Team Foundation Server,
>   work item types are completely
>   customizable, which allows your team
>   to define the fields, rules, state
>   model, and form layout that make sense
>   for your team.

Also you can use more simple thing: [Tasktop](http://tasktop.com/products/visual-studio/)

Description:

> Tasktop for Visual Studio brings
>   **Eclipse Mylyn's task list** and connectors into the Microsoft Visual
>   Studio IDE.

Addon is free.

Comment: Edited my answer: added addon link and description.